# How to stop air leak in exterior door aluminum sill?

Tags: doors, sealing, aluminum, weatherstripping, sill

I found that one of my exterior doors are leaking cold air from beneath the door sill.

[image]

The product installed is Endura Z-Articulating Cap Sill™ and Sealing System

[image]

How can I seal it?
Can I use silicone around the aluminum sill?
Should I only seal from outside?

Comment: If you attempt to caulk it from the inside, you'll want to do a very nice job of it, since you'll see this caulk line. I'd suggest doing the outside first, then give it a while. If you _need_ to, add a bead of caulk on the inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the subfloor is concrete. you can use a silicone, urethane, or acrylic caulk.

If silicone be sure to get one that's suited to concrete and aluminium.